# Is thinking about having sex with porn stars haram?

Tags: halal-haram, sex, pornography

If you know the face and body of a porn star well. But you don't whatch the Video. You close your eyes and think about what you have seen before and imagine you are doing sex with the porn star. But do not masturbate or even touch your body. Is this action haram?

What about this imagination to a girl you see in a park ?

Answer (score 1):

> حَدَّثَنَا مُسْلِمُ بْنُ إِبْرَاهِيمَ، حَدَّثَنَا هِشَامٌ، عَنْ
>   قَتَادَةَ، عَنْ زُرَارَةَ بْنِ أَوْفَى، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، عَنِ
>   النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏ "‏ إِنَّ اللَّهَ تَجَاوَزَ
>   لأُمَّتِي عَمَّا لَمْ تَتَكَلَّمْ بِهِ أَوْ تَعْمَلْ بِهِ وَبِمَا
>   حَدَّثَتْ بِهِ أَنْفُسَهَا ‏"‏
>
> Abu Hurairah reported the Prophet (ﷺ) as saying “Allah has ignored for my community what comes to their mind, so long as they do not act or pronounce words to that effect.” ([Source](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/13/35))

this is form the normal what we see in the street but about thinking about actors or bad people how can you draw a picture of them without watching them 
so for the imagination of actors and bad people  it can be taken under this

> Ibn ‘Aabideen al-Hanafi (may Allaah have mercy on him) said:
>
> The view that is closest to the spirit of our madhhab is that it is
>   not permissible, because imagining that woman as if he is having
>   intercourse with her is imagining oneself committing a sin with a
>   woman who is not permissible for him.

**and there is different opinion and more details** about other imagination for women in street and job 
you can read about it here [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/84066)

والله اعلم

Answer (score -1):

Its not a good thing to think about sex, because thinking about having sex make bad kind of thinking . Although there is a Hadith of our beloved Holy prophet (SAW). The summary of this Hadith is thinking about wrong things we don't get sinful until we don't commit that wrong thing and thinking about good we are given reward even if we are not able to do that good thing.

Comment: But as more you think about it one day you will commit it